# Can I use ITfoxtec saml2 to add a SAML identity provider to a non-Core website?

Tags: saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have an OIDC identity provider I want to extend to be a SAML2 identity provider, but it is not a .NET Core site. The test/samples only show how to configure a core app.

Is it possible to use it to make an identity provider for a non-core site?

Answer (score 0):

The ITfoxtec Identity SAML2 component both support implementing a identity provider (IdP) on .NET core and .NET Framework. 
Yes, there is only a .NET Core sample `TestIdPCore` showing how to implement an IdP. But I think you relatively easy can port the sample code to .NET Framework by looking at the .NET Framework sample `TestWebApp`.